# How can I get a list of installed fonts using Adobe Air?

Tags: fonts, air

I've found a method for finding the list of installed fonts in JavaScript in IE but this does not work when moved to Air. This is because it uses an IE object, dlgHelper.

I've seen several applications in Air that give a list of fonts and I'm wondering how they get it? Are they simply investigating the fonts folder on Windows? Is there a better way to query the operating system that would work cross-platform?

I'm trying to create a text editor that doesn't rely on embedded fonts. I want to use a menu of fonts as you would find in any "real" desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AIR, using actionscript 3 you would use [Font.enumerateFonts()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts%28%29) ?
If you're using actionscript 3 fine, otherwise, you might want to have 1x1 swf that will communicate to javascript and pass the font values over.

HTH

Comment: Funny, I just found the answer before seeing your post! Thanks a lot, because that was just what I was searching for.